# Really simple Excel SUMIF not working

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to calculate the total from D2 to D17 only if the cells between C2 to C17 contain the number "9". I tried to use the formula `=SUMIF(C2:C17,9,D2:D17)`, but it wouldn't work!

The odd part is that if I put in another criteria such as "4" or 50", it would return the sum. It just doesn't work with some numbers.

Here's a screenshot of the 
SUMIF if I put 9 as my criteria

[image]

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Look like the formula is fine, but you are summing the value "0" to the highlighted cell containing the formula, because D17 = 0, and that cell corresponds the "9" value - so the sum you get is, as expected, 0.

[image]

Comment: Ahh I don't know how I didn't see that before, thank you so much! I'll use a countif formula then